# How do we integrate ckfinder in ckeditor in ANGULAR 6?

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckfinder

Hi I have been trying to integrate the ckeditor5 with angular app and followed instruction given in the 
document.

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/image-upload/ckfinder.html

Normal ckeditor5 is working but when i'm trying to enable ckfinder with it, it is not working.
Specifically I'm trying to upload an image to server, and need to do some basic operations like image reszing
metioned in the CKFinder.
As per the doc, when we click on the ckfinder button , it should open the modal box but right now its not opening "

Appreciate your time  and thanks in advance

I'm pasting my files for your reference

app.component.html

```
<ckeditor
[(ngModel)]="model.editorData"
[editor]="Editor"
[config]="{
toolbar: ['ckfinder'],
ckfinder: {
  options: {
    resourceType: 'Images'
  },
  uploadUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/test/upload/iamge'
 }
}"
></ckeditor>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
title = 'ckeditor2';

public Editor = ClassicEditor;
public model = {
 editorData: '<p>Hello, world!</p>'
};}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [AppComponent],
   imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     AppRoutingModule,
     FormsModule,
     NgxEditorModule,
     HttpClientModule,
     AngularFontAwesomeModule,
     CKEditorModule
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
export class AppModule {}
```

[image]

Comment: did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @Matthew Not yet, Intead I used 'tinymce'
https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-angular

Answer (score 2):

Just include

```
<script src="ckeditor.com/apps/ckfinder/3.4.5/ckfinder.js"></script>
```

into index.html file and it will work!